# golang with protobuf with dep

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

how am I supposed to use golang protobufs with dep. If I create a project $GOPATH/src/my_test . My main problems:

- protobuf requires that code is generated with a compatible compiler to the library. How to tell dep to download compiler code when it's not used in code and it gets pruned?
- If I have 2 protobufs outside go repo that have structure  proto_root/users/user.go and proto_root/people/person.go  and one references another, where should I generate code so that the generate code looks up the libraries in vendor folders?

Comment: Have you tried using go modules instead of dep?

Comment: no because they are experimental opt-in feature. not until it's ready

Answer (score 0):

It seems that if I configure the dep GOPKG.toml to require my protobuf folders and the compiler I can call

```
dep ensure -add github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go
```

I can build the compiler and the code won't be pruned. And set --go_out to the vendor folder. Seems to be working